# Normalizing the URL using javascript (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, url, normalization

1) How to normalize the url?
for example 
if input is **cnn.com**

output should be **https://www.edition.cnn.com** (<- this is the url of **cnn.com**)
is there any library in node.j?

what i found is "normalize-url" library `https://www.npmjs.com/package/normalize-url`

what it does is, It is taking url as a input but won't append the **www** to the url for example
input is google.com

output is :-

**http://google.com**

Comment: You can probably just make a request and see if you get redirected or not and just return the final URL. However, you need to make a network request for each URL. I doubt there is a library or anything that holds all mappings of all URLs to what they actually lead to *and* that gets updated regularly enough.

Comment: @VLAZ could you tell me how to achieve it ,is there any source to refer

Comment: The standart perl package [LWP::UserAgent](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent) has response chain of [redirects](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Response#$r-%3Eredirects)

Comment: @oklas but i need it in javascript bro

Comment: @RAJENDRA H That was seemed to me that VLAZ say about any library in the world, but now I see that was not exactly such. I just remember about that feature in lwp. If no such things for node googled and use perl is not a case then it is time to write your own (may be make a library).

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the library of `normailze-url` there are options you can use e.g.
`normalizeUrl(url, { stripWWW: false }).` then you get your `www`
Regards
mathias